# Question on training with label and unlabeled data

Tags: arabic, training-data, supervised-learning, semisupervised-learning

I have a large labeled dataset with 26.7M reviews written in Modern standard Arabic, and I have another dataset but unlabeled with 16K reviews written in both Modern standard Arabic and colloquial Arabic.

What are the possible and correct approaches to label the unlabeled dataset? when the goal is also to increase the accuracy?

Provide me with some examples in python that could help.